# Error writing to file "is private to #<PROCESS worker( )"

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slime, ccl

I'm just beginning with CL, I'm using CCL+Slime with Emacs v24 in Windows XP64. I am experiencing the following problem:

If I enter these three expressions in the REPL, I get the intended result, a file with the text "Something" in it:

```
(defparameter *file-out*
  (open "e:/test.txt"
      :direction :output
      :if-exists :supersede
      :if-does-not-exist :create))

(write-line "Something" *file-out*)

(close *file-out*)
```

But if the same code is in a text buffer and I evaluate the expressions one by one with C-c C-c, I get this error when evaluating the (write ...) statement:

```
Stream #<BASIC-FILE-CHARACTER-OUTPUT-STREAM ("e:/test.txt"/2616 UTF-8) #x2180C0A06D> is private to #<PROCESS worker(46) [Reset] #x2180BB558D>
[Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]
```

What can be the cause? Thanks for your help.

**Edit:**

I've found this in the backtrace, so the error seems to come from (CCL::CHECK-IOBLOCK-OWNER ...), which says the owner is "PROCESS Worker(31)":

```
0: (CCL::CHECK-IOBLOCK-OWNER #S(CCL::FILE-IOBLOCK :STREAM #<BASIC-FILE-CHARACTER-OUTPUT-STREAM ("e:/apps/gcj/2008-0-A-large-practice.out"/1600 UTF-8) #x2180AA709D> :UNTYI-CHAR NIL :INBUF ...))
    Locals:
    IOBLOCK = #S(CCL::FILE-IOBLOCK :STREAM #<BASIC-FILE-CHARACTER-OUTPUT-STREAM ("e:/apps/gcj/2008-0-A-large-practice.out"/1600 UTF-8) #x2180AA709D> :UNTYI-CHAR NIL :INBUF ...)
    OWNER = #<PROCESS worker(31) [Reset] #x2180AA2B5D>
```

I did the following test to see who owns the file streams:

- I opened two different files, *file-out1* and *file-out2*, from the REPL, when trying to write to them from a test buffer with C-c C-c, I get the error saying the owner is "worker(12)".
- I opened *file-out1* from the test buffer with C-c C-c, when trying to writ to it from the test buffer or the REPL or anywhere else, I get the error saying the owner is "worker(30)".
- I opened *file-out2* from the test buffer with C-c C-c, when trying to writ to it from the test buffer or the REPL or anywhere else, I get the error saying the owner is "worker(31)".
- I ran the test buffer (open, write, and close file) at once with C-c C-k and it worked.

**Conclusion:**

The REPL has a Worker process ID which doesn't change, but evaluations issued from a separate buffer (C-c C-c or C-c C-k) generate a new Worker process each time. Can someone explain the whole "Worker process" stuff?

**Edit:**

I re-tested in Linux and I obtain the same behavior than in Windows, to avoid confusion, I removed the parts about Linux

Comment: Hmm, C-c C-c with linux,emacs,slime & sbcl works for me strange. I will try on windows 7 later.

Comment: Have tested using win7,emacs,slime & sbcl and it works there too. Sorry I cant give more help here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll continue trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer from **RG** in [comp.lang.lisp](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.lisp/f3-cQoEMb5U): the default behavior of (open ...) in CCL is to give the ownership of the stream to the process that first attempted an I/O operation on it. This can be overriden with the argument **:sharing :lock**. This is documented in http://ccl.clozure.com/ccl-documentation.html#CCL-Stream-Extensions.

I tested and now it works as expected.